# El programa Ionic me hace el build pero no me genera el APK

Tags: android, ionic, windows, apk

Estaba trabajando con *Ionic* y quería que mi proyecto generara el *APK* para poder subirlo a *Play Store*, creé una plataforma de *Android* con el comando `ionic cordova platform add android` y funcionó. Luego quise crear el *APK* con el comando `ionic cordova build android`, y también me funcionó, pero no generó ni el *APK* ni la dirección. Donde la pone solo me sale como en la imagen que puse.

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres crear una apk para probarla en tu celular puedes hacerlo usando el comando (Última versión del Cli de IONIC):

```
$ ionic cordova run android --device
```

Recuerda que debes tener tu Móvil conectado a través de USB y habilitado como desarrollador.

Si lo que quieres es crear la apk para subirla a play Store, ya debes hacer un proceso un poco más largo que explican claramente aquí http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html, recuerda que también debes tener una cuenta de desarrollador de Android, que si no estoy mal cuesta alrededor de 30USD.

Saludos